# how to build docker-ce engine and an own image for Tizen?

Tags: docker, moby

Currently, I'm doing POC of docker in Tizen OS for arm architecture. I just want to know how to build an own image.

Downloaded the code from "https://github.com/moby/moby."

Stuck with below todo,

1) whats the build command in Linux, a host pc which we are using for the build?

2) where to make the changes for setting the arm cross compiler path for docker build?

3) The Tizen kernel which we are using is 4.4/armv7/32bit, should we need to enable any specific configs? some idea we got here

4) On successful build, where the docker engine image will reside in the build?

Comment: I think you may use GBS https://source.tizen.org/ko/documentation/reference/git-build-system?langredirect=1